# A point of light moving between the stars

Tags: identify-this-object

I noticed you replied to a question before about this topic and i came across your answer. Way back in the 80s when i was in my teens i saw a point of light moving between the stars at a steady rate across the sky. It was about the same size and brightnesz of those visible. It was moving in such a was as it approached a star ir veered off left or right then continued on its original path across the night sky. I showed my sister who was older than me at the time. It kind of reminded me of a whiplash efect using gravity to maintain spèed. Mabie too much Star Trek, but you get the idea. I am not an astronomer so forgive my ignorance, but a plane or a satalite would not move in this manor would it? I am convinced to this day that it was not one of ours. Can you clarify this as it was definately avoiding the stars?

Comment: Alex, why would the UFO "avoid" the stars? Do you think it was avoiding a collision?  You do realise, don't you, that whatever you saw was no more than 1000 km away, whereas the nearest star is over 40,000,000,000,000 km away?

Answer (score 3):

It's almost definitely not alien, if that's what you're asking.

A satellite in low Earth orbit (around 200 km altitude) would have needed to move about 60m in the time you noticed it for the movement to have been visible. So, given that satellites at this altitude generally travel at around 7km/s or 7000 metres per second, it is not inconceivable that it could have been a man-made satellite correcting its orbit.